# Register ModelListener<JournalArticle> in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I'm trying to implement a ModelListener in Liferay 7. When I'm updating a JournalArticle in the UI, I would like to add a small behaviour and some logging.

```
@Component(immediate = true, service = ModelListener.class)
public class DownloadsListener extends BaseModelListener<JournalArticle> {

  @Reference
  private StructureService structureService;

  @Reference
  private DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil fileEntryLocalService;

  private static final Log LOG = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(DownloadsListener.class);

  @Override
  public void onAfterUpdate(JournalArticle model) throws ModelListenerException {
    LOG.error("UPDATES!");
    LOG.error("UPDATES!");
    super.onAfterUpdate(model);
    if(structureService.isNieuwsArticle(model)) {
    }

    getFileFromURL("/documents/82177/0/file.pdf/0d10338c-8ca1-c5b7-cc4b-011bef1ee759");
  }

  private DLFileEntry getFileFromURL(String url) {
    String[] splittedURL = StringUtil.split(url, '/');
    return null;    
  }
}
```

But this code is never triggered when I'm updating an article. I'm not hitting my debug point in the onAfterUpdate method, and I'm not seeing any logging. The OSGI Module is deployed correctly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my ModelListener was not being correctly deployed in the OSGi container. (Although Eclipse / Apache Gogo told everything was fine).

OSGi could not resolve:

```
@Reference
private DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil fileEntryLocalService;
```

Changed it to

```
@Reference
private DLFileEntryLocalService fileEntryLocalService;
```

Now the behaviour is correctly. It's a shame that there is ZERO feedback by Apache GoGo.

Comment: I guess you're just looking at the wrong place: If you look for an active Bundle, e.g. using `lb`: That's probably fine - because the classes are all available. If you look at the active service/component, e.g. `scr info`, you'd have seen this. Note that the `@Reference` to a Util class is technically correct - just that nobody would ever declare a service under that class' name, thus it'll never be satisfied.

Comment: +1 for "@Reference to a Util class is technically correct - just that nobody would ever declare a service under that class' name, thus it'll never be satisfied."